# Which is more memory efficient, Threaded Entities or Threaded Sectors for a Java Game?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management

I'm working on shoot 'em up game, that I'm planning on flooding the screen with entities, (Bullets, Mobs, and the like).  I've tried a global timer to update everything on the screen, but I've gotten some serious fps drop when I flood the screen like I want.

So, I see myself as having two options.  I can either give each individual entity a timer Thread, or I can section off the level into chunks and give each chunk its own timer.

With the first scenario, entities with their own timer threads, I will end up with hundreds of entities, each with their own thread running a timer.

In the section option, I will have multiple sections of the map with a timer updating multiple entities at once, with detections for when an entity leaves from one section to another.

I'm not familiar with Programming with Memory Efficiency in mind, so which method would be better for me to use?

Comment: I don't know about games, but I have seen a particle interaction simulator that sections off an area into a grid, and lets each CPU handle its own section. When a particle crosses the border, the ex-owner sends a message to the new owner thread/process/CPU.

Comment: 1 Thread per entity sounds like a bad idea. Too much scheduling, memory consumption etc. Each CPU core can run only 1 thread at a time. If they don't sleep all the time use no more than you have cores (or thread execution units - 1 i7 core can do 2 threads via hyperthreading - so "core" is somewhat incorrect)

Comment: 1 thread per entity is the some CUDA/OpenCL.

Comment: ArjunShanker, do you have a link to the simulator you mentioned, and is it open source?  I would love to read how they have it set up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

It's part of the [Java higher-level concurrency API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html). You can decide how many threads should exist (it re-uses threads for different tasks to avoid the overhead of creating new ones every time and is therefore expected to be much more efficient than creating new Threads all the time) or use a cached thread pool (which will create as many threads are necessary, but once a Thread has died it will re-use it to run new tasks).

Another advantage of this API is that not only can you run Runnables, you can also use Callables, which may return a value for you to use in the future (so you can perform calculations in different Threads and then use the result of each Thread for a final result).

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting with something similar and don't have a definite answer. But maybe some of the feedback I got from Java-Gaming.org will be helpful or of interest.

What I tried was this: each entity has its own thread, and collisions are handled via a very detailed map of the screen (basically a second version of the screen). Then, I have another thread that handles the display of the screen.

An "early" version of this, with over 500 entities being animated, is online:
http://hexara.com/pond.html

Later versions use more elaborate shapes and borders (rather than letting entities die and freeze at the edges) and collision logic such as bouncing off of each other and gravity. I was also playing with sprite aspects like "firefly" blinking. I mention "actors" on the web page, but the code isn't strictly that.

Some folks at java-gaming.org strongly thought having so many threads was not efficient. There was a lot of interesting feedback from them, which you might be interested in exploring. I haven't had time yet.
http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/multi-threading-and-collision-detection/25967/view.html

They were discussing things like hyperthreading and the acca framework for Actors.